# Print only those Months that have 31 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL so I am practicing different problems and unfortunately I'm stuck with one of them.

### Date Column

```
| HIREDATE  |
| --------- |
| 17-NOV-81 |
| 01-MAY-81 |
| 09-JUN-81 |
| 02-APR-81 |
| 19-APR-87 |
| 03-DEC-81 |
| 17-DEC-80 |
| 20-FEB-81 |
| 22-FEB-81 |
| 28-SEP-81 |
| 08-SEP-81 |
| 23-MAY-87 |
| 03-DEC-81 |
| 23-JAN-82 |
```

### Problem

Here I am trying to list only those dates in which their specific months has  **31 days**
I am using `Last_Day()` function but it shows **Error:** `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER`.

This is the Query I am using:

```
SELECT ENAME, HIREDATE FROM scott.emp WHERE LAST_DAY(HIREDATE)=31;
```

I also tried to Extract Day from date but still its not working  and showing the same Error.

```
SELECT ENAME, HIREDATE FROM scott.emp WHERE LAST_DAY(EXTRACT(DAY FROM HIREDATE))=31
```

As I am a beginner so I am using **Oracle Live SQL**

Is there any other way of Listing only those dates that has just 31 days in Oracle SQL?

Comment: I think that last day function returns date and not number. Can't compare those two.

Comment: so, Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You could try EXTRACT day out of the date.

Comment: You need the day from LAST_DAY not the HIREDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT ENAME, HIREDATE FROM scott.emp WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(HIREDATE)) = 31;
```

Comment: Your query is not the same

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use `TO_CHAR` function with appropriate format mask:

```
SQL> select ename, hiredate from emp
  2  where to_char(last_day(hiredate), 'dd') = '31';

ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ----------
SMITH      17.12.1980
BLAKE      01.05.1981
SCOTT      09.12.1982
ADAMS      12.01.1983
JAMES      03.12.1981
FORD       03.12.1981
MILLER     23.01.1982

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```